# TypeScript error. Fixed but can't explain it

Tags: typescript

Broken Code:

```
ngOnInit(){
    Observable.fromEvent(this.el.nativeElement, 'keyup')
    .map((e:any) => {e.target.value})
    .filter((text:string) => text.length < 3)
    .debounceTime(250)
    .do(() => this.loading.next(true))
    //search youtube
    .map((query: string)=> {this.youtube.search(query)})
}
```

Error:

[ts]
The type argument for type parameter 'T' cannot be inferred from the usage. Consider specifying the type arguments explicitly.
  Type argument candidate 'void' is not a valid type argument because it is not a supertype of candidate 'string'.
any

Fix:

If I remove the curly brackets from e.target.value (3rd line), everything is ok. Why would that be the case?

Answer (score 1):

Coming from a C# background here, but I think the same logic applies to TypeScript.

Curly braces allows you to enter multiple lines of code in a lambda e.g.

```
.map((e:any) => {
    console.log('Hello');
    return e.target.value;
})
```

That means you need to use `return e.target.value;` when using curly braces, so that the code block returns a value to satisfy the requirements of the `map` function.

Not using curly braces results in `e.target.value` being implicitly returned from the call to `map`, thus no need to include `return`.

Answer (score 0):

They correspond to 2 syntaxes of [ES6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Use_of_the_new_operator), namely:

```
(param1, param2, …, paramN) => { statements }
(param1, param2, …, paramN) => expression
```

That make `tsc` inferred return types to be different:

```
.map((e:any) => {e.target.value})
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     an arrow function that have no return, and effectively returns undefined.
     TypeScript compiler infers such function to have return type "void".

.map((e:any) => e.target.value)
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     an arrow function that returns e.target.value
     the compiler inters the return type to be "any"
```

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. Thanks.